# Passing date value from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my model I have

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime SaleDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customers { get; set; }
```

in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="SaleID,shippingBillNo,CustomerID,PlantID,Quantity,SaleDate")] Sale sale)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var strddlValue = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["CustomerID"]);
            var saledate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["mySaleDate"]);
```

In my View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Sale</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerID, "CustomerID", new { 
        @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Hidden("CustomerText")
                @Html.DropDownList("CustomerID", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID)
            </div>
        </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SaleDate, new { @class = "control- 
                label col-md-2" })   
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SaleDate, new { Name = 
                 "mySaleDate"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SaleDate)
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the JavaScript for the DateTimePicker is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#SaleDate').datetimepicker({
        format: "DD/MM/YYYY"
    }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
        $(this).data('DateTimePicker').hide();
    });
});
```

I succeed to pass the CustomerID to the controller. No Problem with that. Instead of passing the date I pick in the editofor with the DataTimePicker helper I get a meaningless value of '01/01/0001'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sounds like your passing a formated date from the controler to the model as MM/DD/YYYY and expecting the datetimepicker to handle that.  I would look at what was generated here  '@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SaleDate, new { Name = 
                 "mySaleDate"})'

Comment: To avoid these kinds of problems, pass the date in ISO8601 formatted string then parse it on the server.

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript correctly, to avoid search collision with Java.

Comment: Under no circumstances do you ever attempt to change the `name` attribute (using `new { Name = "mySaleDate" }` - although fortunately that dos absolutely nothing in your case). What is the culture on your server? - is it one that expects dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format?

Comment: If your EditorFor is generating `<input type="date" />` markup, your value must be formatted as an ISO-8601 date, as Jasen mentioned. ISO-8601 dates are `yyyy-MM-dd`. Anything else will be considered invalid by the native date input. Regardless, you need to update your question to indicate what plugin you're using.